# primefaces value expression on DefaultMenuItem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi i trying to set value expresion on some attribute (for example attribute class) of DefaultMenuItem of Primefaces. Something like:

```
  <p:menuitem class="#{view.viewId.endsWith('index.xhtml') ? 'menuitm-hovered' : ''}" value="Home" url="/"  />
```

exaclty these peace

```
  class="#{view.viewId.endsWith('index.xhtml') ? 'menuitm-hovered' : ''}"
```

but programaticaly. On bean should be something like these:

```
  menuItem.setValueExpression("class", Helper2.createValueExpression("#{view.viewId.endsWith('index.xhtml') ? 'menuitm-hovered' : ''}", Object.class));
```

DefaultMenuItem dosent have setValueExpression method so im stuck and I dont know how i could do that. If someone could help i will be grateful for help.

As far as i know setValueExpression can be done in GraphicImage (in these case with value attribute)

```
    GraphicImage image = new GraphicImage();
    image.setValueExpression("value", Helper2.createValueExpression("#{position.images.link}", Object.class));
```

Below static method of Helper2 class:

```
 public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String expression, Class clazz) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expFactory = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression ret = expFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, clazz);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
item = new UIMenuItem();

item.setValue(command.getLabel());
item.setActionExpression(Utility.createMethodExp(command.getCommandExpression()));
item.setValueExpression("disabled", Utility.createExpression(command.getDisabledExpression(), Boolean.class));

menuButton.getChildren().add(item);
```

where Utility.createMethodExpression is a static method (of my class Utility):

```
public static MethodExpression createMethodExp(String stringExpression) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(Utility.getELContext(),
            stringExpression, Void.class, new Class[] {});
}
```

and Utility.createExpression is

```
public static ValueExpression createExpression(String stringExpression, Class<?> type) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(context.getELContext(),
            stringExpression, type);
}
```